# Is there danger in installing 2 versions of Anaconda for Python on one machine?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

Some background: I have an intel Mac osx (running Yosemite) and use PyCharm community edition as my main IDE. I usually code in Python 3.4 however, I'm taking some MIT OCW courses which all use Python 2. To make it easier on myself when using MIT's skeleton files I have downloaded Python 2.7 and switch the PyCharm interpreter depending on my project.

Here's my question:

I'm wondering if I would run into any trouble downloading the 2.7 and 3.4 versions of Anaconda.

If this is ok, would I need to do anything special with my import commands depending on which version of Python I'm coding in?

Thanks! Happy to add clarity / more info if this isn't enough to answer my questions.

Comment: No you won't have any problems.

Comment: installing  several versions of anaconda is usually not necessary. With a 2.7 version you can install python3.4 environments and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There's no danger, but it's also not the recommended way of achieving this. Rather, you should use `conda`, the package manager that comes with Anaconda, to create an environment for the other version of Python.  For instance, if you started with Anaconda3,

```
conda create -n python27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

would create an environment called `python27` in ~/anaconda/envs/python27 with Python 2.7 and all the packages from Anaconda. You would then point to ~/anaconda/bin/python or ~/anaconda/envs/python27/bin/python depending on what version of Python you want.  In the terminal, use `source activate python27` and `source deactivate` to switch between the two.

See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/ for more information on conda.